# .net 7.0 dockerize with swagger

Tags: dockerfile, swagger, .net-7.0

I have a project with .net 7.0. This normally works with Swagger interface when it works with Visual Studio. However, I want to Dockerize the application. I created the image. I created the Container, but I can't access the Swagger interface. Is there anyone who has information about the subject who can help?
Thanks for your help.

Here's mine dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:49901
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GlobalServices2/GlobalServices2.csproj", "GlobalServices2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "GlobalServices2/GlobalServices2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/GlobalServices2"
RUN dotnet build "GlobalServices2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GlobalServices2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GlobalServices2.dll"]
```

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:49901
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GlobalServices2/GlobalServices2.csproj", "GlobalServices2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "GlobalServices2/GlobalServices2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/GlobalServices2"
RUN dotnet build "GlobalServices2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GlobalServices2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GlobalServices2.dll"]

Comment: Do you map ports when starting container?